# Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client dll is missing

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to generate lookup tables in SharePoint and taking reference from a sample project. Here is the code snippet I'm referring to:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; 
using Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client;   
using System.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PWA_CSOM
{
    public partial class FinalLogic_Second : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        #region veriables
        private static ProjectContext projContext;
        string pwaPath = "";
        string userId = "";
        string userPassword = "";
    }
}
```

I have created a new project and created a variable to type `ProjectContext`, however I'm not able to find the reference for it. I have tried everywhere but no luck:

```
using Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client;   //Missing Reference

namespace LookupTable
{
    public static class Infrastructure
    {
        #region Properties
        public ProjectContext project;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I tried Local Assembly Reference but no luck - 
[image: Local Reference]

Also tried the Nuget Reference - 
[image]

Is there something missed from my end? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install SharePoint Online CSOM package in Package Manager Console in Visual studio.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM -Version 16.1.7723.1200
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed [Project Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/project/project-server-2013-and-2016) you can do this.

As mentioned [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.projectserver.client_di_pj14mref.aspx) ,
You can reference to  this library again by just going into this path and select the dll file.

> %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll